# How to make a link beneath a div clickable

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, z-index

I have a link under a div with 100% height and width in a fixed position and z-index: 5.
I need to keep this div above my link, but the link doesn't work.
Can I make the link work but keep this div above my link?

**https://jsfiddle.net/8hu90e9x/1/**

```css
div {
  background:grey;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  opacity:0.5;
  z-index:5
}

a {
  font-size:50px;
  z-index:0
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com"> My link</a>

<div></div>
```

Comment: You cannot do it, but you can set your `a` with `display: block;` and use it as a `div`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add [`pointer-events:none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to the CSS rules for your div

```css
div {
  background:grey;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  opacity:0.5;
  z-index:5;
  pointer-events:none;
}

a {
  font-size:50px;
  z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com"> My link</a>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of this div is just to change the background color, it would be easier to delete it and do this instead:

```
body{
    background-color:lightgrey;
}
```